# Why am I getting output from other tags? XML/XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm using XSLT 1.0 to convert XML to HTML, however I'm getting undesired output. Why am I getting "data.flow2" in my comment msg

The XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CommentsList>
  <Comment>
    <CommentBy>data.flow2</CommentBy>
    <CommentMsg>Set Under Study</CommentMsg>

  </Comment>
  <Comment>
    <CommentBy>data.flow2</CommentBy>
    <CommentMsg>True Files</CommentMsg>

  </Comment>
  <Comment>
    <CommentBy>data.flow2</CommentBy>
    <CommentMsg>
      <![CDATA[<a     href='http://eservices.saudieng.sa/Attachments/DataFlowReports/ce2cd49ac33e45edb8902c7d074d    908a.pdf'>Download the Report</a>]]> </CommentMsg>

  </Comment>
</CommentsList>
```

This is the xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CommentsList">
      <table border="1">
        <tr style="background-color:lightblue">
          <td>Comment By</td>
          <td>Comment Msg</td>
          <td>Comment Date</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/CommentsList/Comment">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="CommentBy"/>
            </td>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="/CommentsList/Comment[3]/CommentMsg">
                <td>
                  <CommentMsg>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                  </CommentMsg>
                </td>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <td>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </td>
             </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>


          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output for the comment msg is like this:

data.flow2 [comment msg text]

Why am I not getting the comment msg text only??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're doing a `value-of select="."` when the context node is a `Comment`. The string value of an element is defined to be the concatenation of all it's descendant text nodes, so for the `Comment` this would be the concatenation of the `CommentBy` and `CommentMsg` element content.

Use `select="CommentMsg"` instead.